# How to modify client id (cookie value) using google Analytics on click of button?

Tags: google-analytics

I am using following line to change the cookie parameter but no change in the clientId/ Cookie Value. Please help me with the solution.

```
ga('set', 'clientId', "value");
```

Comment: but why you need like this?

Comment: I need to store mobile number in the client but on page load i do not have that, so default client id is stored in the cookie but later in one of page  I have number that number I want to replace with the default client id.

Comment: so in my knowledge you can use `jquery cookies` plugin or `localStorage` to store & pass value to `clientId`. because it's not possible through click event.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the client id when you create the tracker:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', {
  'clientId': '<my custom clientid>'
});
```

Once the tracker is created you cannot change it. Changing the client id will end the session and create a new user, so you'll loose all related information (traffic source  etc.).

This is documented behaviour inasfar as [clientid is listed in the "Create Only Fields" section of the analytics.js field reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference).

Comment: Indeed, it looks like the library prevents you from changing the `clientId` after the tracker has been created. However, I can't find any documentation of this behaviour - can you?

Comment: Updated the answer - it is easy to miss since you'd have to look at the section headline, not the field description.